# Gap in conduit running to electric meter

Tags: electrical, conduit

There's a gap in the conduit running from underground to my electric meter.  I'm sure that's a problem, since weather could get in.  It appears to be PVC.

The question is: Can I service this myself, or do I need to get an electrician?  I would rather not electrocute myself, especially when dealing with wires that might be carrying a lot of voltage.  It seems like such a simple fix -- but I don't want to take any chances.

Is it safe if I try to get the PVC to line up, and fasten it in place, without touching the wires inside?  Do I need to contact the utility and have the electricity turned off before attempting something like this?

Or is it worth the $ to get a professional to deal with this?

[image: conduit]

Comment: is that an earth rod on the right? it looks kind of skinny.

Comment: That looks like an expansion joint that pulled apart.  It’s designed to allow for the ground to settle without breaking the pipe.   Either there was a lot of ground settlement or it was improperly installed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't sweat it.

Wires that are used underground are pretty tough, and are well waterproofed, if water gets in there no harm will be done.

the cable run to the meter is usually maintained by the electricity supplier, so you could contact them for assistance but they will probably not do much.

I see a wide bit and a narrow bit pf conduit, if you line them up the wide bit might slide down to cover the gap.

there's a chance that the conduit might crack when you try to bend it. it depends how old it is. if that hapens call the power company.

if you want an easy  DIY fix slit a piece of PVC tube or conduit so you can clip it over the gap and fasten it with hose clamps.  this won't be waterproof but it will keep fingers out.

Comment: I contacted the utility company, and they said it’s my responsibility. I checked some online documentation from the utility, and it seems to support what they told me. The only thing they’d take responsibility for is the meter itself, and of course the main transmission lines.

Comment: Is it safe to work on this myself?

Comment: Is this not the main line into your meter?  So long as the plastic insulation on the wires is intact it is safe, poke it with a dry piece of wood, or ghard plastic (but not a pencil) if it seems good it almost certainly is.

Comment: Yes, that's where the power enters the meter. I figured it would be the utility's responsibility.  But according to this diagram, it's the homeowner's responsibility.  And it seems like most other electric utilities are the same way.  (Homeowner is responsible for items in black, utility for items in blue). https://i.imgur.com/qdIcxgw.jpg